# MySQL query runs twice

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have an php file in which I include the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: `include("simple_html_dom.php");` 
This inclusion makes my `mysql_query($query)` execute twice on my page - if I remove the inclusion , the `mysql_query` runs fine - I also tried to put the inclusion after the query - same problem!

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (abc) VALUES ('ok8')");
echo "x";
include("simple_html_dom.php");
```

This results in 2 rows of my table but a single "x" in browser. (Also tried to put the `echo` before). Please, help!

Comment: Is that the complete code, or do you do anything else as well? Is that the exact query or do you build it dynamically?

Comment: This is a silly question, but maybe `simple_html_dom.php` runs the same query>

Comment: what is the code for simple_html_dom.php?

Comment: how do you call this code? is it cli or by apache? take a look into access log if possible, your script can be called twice... ( just a thought )

Comment: The query is the one in the question, the simple_html_dom.php - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do you have any redirects/mod_rewrite in effect on your server? Those'd result in two seperate requests, with the second one's 'x' replacing the first one's. Check your server's access logs to see how many hits are generated by one visit to your page.

Comment: Thank you very much but I solved this issue! There was an conflict with a form...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a call to [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace) before `mysql_query()`. That will allow you to track the includes trail.

Comment: Alright, that proves that such line is executed once in the script lifetime. You've somehow managed to run the whole script twice. Firebug's *Net* panel (with the "Persist" option enabled) should reveal that.