# Why Chrome calls my page as XHR after loaded, and executes MySQLi insert twice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-chrome

I make an insert through **mysqli** with a php code in the page.
Now in Chrome my code is **executed twice**, so I receive two record in db, while in other browser it works fine (just one insert).

I suspect, is because Chrome is calling my page again as XHR, but why?!

I read a lot of stuff about it:
[Chrominium issue 38144](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38144&can=2&q=38144&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) and [Chrominium issue 64810](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810) and I've also started a bounty on [php run once and insert twice in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055885/php-run-once-and-insert-twice-in-mysql-database). 
Anyway nothing works good, **fixed favicon**, **removed url rewrite**, **no cache stuffs**, **no htaccess**, but nothing. Also tried to find empty background-image stuff but nothing.

*Microsoft-IIS/7.5* **-** *Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m* **-** *jQuery 1.11.1*

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: `.htaccess` has no effect on `iis` look for `web.config`. Also post your code we're just throwing out guesses with out it.

Comment: you say this is xhr. can you see 2 calls to the page in the console - network tab?

Comment: @chris85 I now, i wrote **htaccess** just because many forum says that this is the problem :/

Comment: @chris85 I solved, was **$.ajax({async:true});** but why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but don't ask me how I understood it, because I removed line by line all my function to debug it.
Was this line of code:

```
$.ajax({async:true})
```

I removed it and now works fine. But why?