# Table update/insert duplicate data using phalcon framework

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following database table

```
+----+---------+------+-------+
| id | title   | code | views |
+----+---------+------+-------+
| 1  | Video 1 | abc  | 1000  |
+----+---------+------+-------+
| 2  | Video 2 | def  | 2000  |
+----+---------+------+-------+
| 3  | Video 3 | ghi  | 3000  |
+----+---------+------+-------+
```

the model `Videos.php`

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Videos extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $code;
    public $views;

}
```

and the controller `IndexController.php`

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction(){

        $watch = Videos::findFirst(3);

        // add +1 to video views
        $watch->views = $watch->views + 1;

        // update video data
        $watch->save();

        // output video data to view
        $this->view->watch = $watch;

    }

}
```

The above code should add +1 in views of the chosen video, but is always adding +2.

Ex: 1000, 1002, 1004, 1006 ...

If I run raw SQL the same thing happens.
Am I doing something wrong?

**Update #1**

I activated the SQL query log and it is running 2 queries at the same time, so the values get duplicated, but I do not know why this.

In this link https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/274/model-save-create-two-records was suggested to check a table with the primary, but already exists, which is the id field.

Comment: Maybe move the solution as answer? :)

Comment: done @Nikolay Mihaylov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by this response 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770447/2587280

The error occurred because Phalcon needs a `.htaccess` file that redirects all requests to`index.php`. Using Google Chrome, by default it tries to load a `favicon.ico` file from the root of the site, but since the file did not exist, it was directed to the `index.php` that was loaded one more time.

To be really sure, I renamed my style.css file to a nonexistent name. Page styles were not applied, Chrome's Inspection returned no 404 error, and in the file response was the full `index.php` code.

To solve the problem, I added a RewriteCond, verifying that the file was not the favicon.ico

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```