# XHTTP request in chrome extension executes twice

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to execute a PHP script on my server from a Chrome extension. Here is the ajax call:

```
      data_array_ = JSON.stringify(data_array_);
      //console.log("Connections array" + data_array_);
      var file_address = "https://my.server/add_on_php_files/update_database.php";
      var xhttp_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var response = this.responseText;
          console.log(response);
        };
      };
      xhttp_request.open("POST", file_address, true);
      xhttp_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp_request.send("data_array=" + data_array_);
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'database.php';
$data_array = $_REQUEST["data_array"];
$data_array_entry = json_decode($data_array, true);
$statement_to_call = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone)  VALUES ";
  $length = count($data_array_entry);
  $index = 0;
foreach($data_array_entry as $single_data) {
  $statement_to_call .= "('".$single_data['name']."','".$single_data['phone']."')";
  if(++$index != $length){
   $statement_to_call .= ", ";
  } else {
   $statement_to_call .= ";";
  }
};
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, $statement_to_call);
echo  $statement_to_call;

?>
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this call without the developer tools open, the script ends up executing a second time, putting additional data into my database (I looked at the server logs and saw that the script executed twice). If I execute the call with the developer tools open, the call only executes once and the network panel and database both show the expected results. Obviously, I cannot expect a user to keep the developer tools open all the time, so this is a problem that I need to solve. Stepping through the Javascript step by step also fails to show me the problem because it also executes with no problems. If the problem occurs when I use it normally but does not occur when I attempt to debug, how can I find the reason why the PHP is executed additional times?

I looked at [php run once and insert twice in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055885/php-run-once-and-insert-twice-in-mysql-database) and saw that people recommended editing the .htaccess to prevent the second call to the PHP file, but when I tried to implement the solution, all of the files on the website became 404'd.
.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?my\.server/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

.htaccess code with attempted .htaccess solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?my\.server/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

The process is triggered by clicking this button:

```
<button class="screen_button" id="add_data">Add data</button>
```

A click event listener was added to the button on startup, thus the button triggers a process that passes a message to the content script and receives a message back that leads to:

```
function get_array_data (contact_array_) {
  //create data to insert
  var data_array_ = [];
  data_array_.push({name: name_1, phone: phone_1});//data retrieved from the content script and passed in through the contact_array_ parameter
  data_array_.push({name: name_2, phone: phone_2});
  //so on so forth
  ajax_call(data_array_);//refer to top of post for the ajax code
}
```

The data is created and sent to the request correctly, and the console.log statement in the ajax callback outputs what I expect it to, and just once. Therefore, I am led to believe that something is causing the PHP file to execute again, independent of the ajax call. The extra PHP file execution doesn't come back and give another console.log.

After additional investigating, I found that the problem seems to start occurring after a specific item in the chrome.storage gets set. I set the variable in chrome storage so I can use it to determine whether to have my content script respond to double-clicking.
The code that toggles the setting (setting is uninitialized until this is called the first time):

```
function toggle_setting () {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["setting"], function(result){
    var setting = result.setting;
    if (setting == "on"){
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"setting": "off"});
    }else{
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"setting": "on"});
    }
  });
}
```

The content script code:

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['setting'], function(result){
    if (result.setting == "on") {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({info: "click", data: contact_data_});
    }
  }
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.message === "get_contacts"){
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({info: "contacts", data: contact_data_});
    }
    //other conditions, etc.
  }
);
```

And the code that listens for the sent messages in the extension environment:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    if(message.info == "click"){
      get_array_data(message.data);
    }else if(message.info == "contacts"){
      get_array_data(message.data);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: It makes two calls to the server? What triggers it?

Comment: Extensions have many moving parts so it's possible you've put this code in the wrong place. Show us how the file with this code is declared and how it's executed.

Comment: @epascarello the trigger is what I'm looking for. I can't find the trigger for the extra call because any time I step through or watch the network panel to debug it works correctly.

Comment: I mean how is that code executed? Seems like it is only partial....

Comment: I tried adding more information on the process that triggers the request in the post.

Comment: Don’t know about the extension environment, but is this a CORS issue of some sort maybe? Is the request method POST in both cases, or is the first one OPTIONS maybe?

Comment: @CBroe the request method is POST in both cases.